# How to exclude a URL from being rewritten by .Net Intelligentia Rewriter

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, telerik

I have a Webforms ASP.Net app that already has multiple rules defined for url rewriting and they are working. the app uses Intelligencia URl Rewriter, which unfortunately has no online/offline documentation whatsoever.

Due to one of these rules, a request for any aspx file is getting redirected to default.aspx, which is fine for all cases except when the aspx is `Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx`.

I tried to use the following configuration in rewriter config to NOT rewrite the url if it contains Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx, but it's not working.

**Question**

How would I exclude the url containing `Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx` from beinng handled by the Url Rewriter?

*Config below is for excluding a url  but it does not work*

```
<rewrite url="^(.+)?Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler\.aspx(\?(.+))?$" to="$1" 
 processing="stop" />
```

An existing rule is causing rewriting when url conatins `Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx` and this rule is as below.

```
<if url="^((?!\.ashx|\.asmx|\.axd|\.gif|\.png|\.jpg|\.ico|\.pdf|\.css|\.js|install|error|auth\.aspx|default\.aspx|popup\.aspx|advanced\.aspx|digest\.aspx|ftb.imagegallery\.aspx|ckfinder).)*$">
    <rewrite url="^~/(.+)?\?(.+)?$" to="~/Default.aspx?g=$1&amp;$2" processing="stop" />
    <rewrite url="^~/(.+)?\.aspx$" to="~/Default.aspx?g=$1" processing="stop" /> 
    <rewrite url="^~/(.+)?$" to="~/Default.aspx?g=$1" processing="stop" />
</if>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer.

To exclude a URL containing the string `Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx`, the following rewrite rule must be placed as the first rule in the rewrite URL config section.

```
 <rewrite url="^(/.*(Telerik\.Web\.UI\.DialogHandler\.aspx)(\?.*)?)$" 
    to="$1" processing="stop" />
```

It's important to place it as the first rule so that the chance of any existing rules applying to this URL is completely eliminated. The `$1` used for to attribute makes sure that original URL is used as the value of to attribute.

Comment: Can you help me @Sunil  ?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47628919/asp-net-url-rewrite-rule